# how can i ignore a line which contains alphanumeric character while reading a text file in python

Tags: python, list, file, file-io

I am reading a text file in python which contains mostly numeric lines along with some alphanumeric lines. I need to segregate odd and even numbers and to write in new files, but i get the error when it goes to alphanumeric lines. please help.
for example.... say txt file contains following....2,4,6,10p etc. I tried with this code. I want this code work as, after writing even and odd to the respective file.... it should say, your job is done but these lines were left as it is.... can we do that??

```
file = open("num.txt","rt")
even = open("even.txt","w+")
odd = open("odd.txt","w+")
for i in file:
    if i.strip:
        num = int(i)
        if (num % 2 == 0):
            even.write(str(num))
            even.write("\n")

        else:
            odd.write(str(num))
            odd.write("\n")
```

But it is showing the following error

```
File "G:/Py_projects/odd_even.py", line 6, in <module>
    num = int(i)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10p\n'
```

Process finished with exit code 1
please reply. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems.

Comment: You can use the string `.isdigit()` function to determine if a string contains only digits.

Comment: `isalnum()` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ch3steR sir i tried that one, infact, i tried with re.findall() also....but it's not working.

Comment: If a line is `2,4,6,10p` do you want to skip the entire line or process the numbers in it?

Comment: @ASHISHPRIYADERSHY I'm a 3rd yr underGrad student. Copy paste your input text files so that we can find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick sir.... lines are like this....line1-1, line2-2,line 3-10p....something like that

Comment: @Ch3steR 1
2
3
4
5
6
10p
4
83
456
497987
4564
6589
5493
321654 this is the content of num.txt..each line contains a number. Similarly6th line is having that alphanumeric character (10p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text file looks like this.

```
test.txt
1
2
3 
4
5
6
10p
4
83
456
497987
4564
6589
5493
321654
```

This should work for you.

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    even=[]
    odd=[]
    alphanum=[]
    for line in f:
        val=line.strip('\n').strip()
        if val.isdigit():
            if int(val)%2==0:
                even.append(int(val))
            else:
                odd.append(int(val))
        else:
            alphanum.append(val)
with open('even.txt','w') as f1:
    for i in even:
        f1.write(str(i)+'\n') #writing even numbers to even.txt file

print(even)
print(odd)
print(alphanum)
```

As suggested by in the comments [AMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11301900/amc) rewrite `val=line.strip('\n').strip()` as `val=line.strip('\n ')`

---

You have to do the same for `odd` and `alphanum`.

output

```
[2, 4, 6, 4, 456, 4564, 321654]
[1, 3, 5, 83, 497987, 6589, 5493]
['10p']
```

Comment: @ASHISHPRIYADERSHY If answer helped you. Please accept this as answer by clicking the tick mark next to answer.It helps community at large in identifying the correct answer.Cheers.

Comment: Can't `.strip('\n').strip()` be written `.strip(\n )`?

Comment: @AMC Yes, you are right. Editing the answer and adding the credits. Thanks for taking your time in improving the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip('\n').strip()
        if line.isdigit():
            if int(line) % 2 == 0:
                with open  ('even.txt', 'w') as e:
                     e.write (line + '\n')
            else:
                with open ('odd.txt', 'w') as o:
                     o.write (line + '\n')
        elif line.isalnum():
            with open ('alphanum.txt', 'w') as a:
                     a.write (line + '\n')
```